# What does non-relational mean in practice for core.logic?

Tags: clojure, clojure-core.logic, minikanren

When trying to understand core.logic throgh the API docs I come across Non-Relational goals and relational goals. I have no idea what this means in practice and why it is important to annotate goals if they are relational or not.

Can you explain with example how the goals are used differently depending on if they are relational or not?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In order to explain what non-relational means we need to revisit what `relational` means.

If you consider pure functions in functional programming, they always return one value, and for the same input arguments, the same output value is returned.

Say for instance:

```
 f(x) = x + 2
```

This function always returns `5` for input value `3`.

But there are many situations were functions are inappropriate, as square root, that has 2 results.

```
 sqrt(4) => 2 and -2
```

Or divide a number by zero, with no results

Seeing a relation as a generalized function, you have:

- Any number of results (zero or more)
- Non deterministic
- in/out arguments can be different for each invocation
- Relationships return *true* if relation is true and *false* otherwise.

In order to convert a function to a relation we set the result as a new parameter:

```
(cons 1 [2]) => [1 2]

(conso 1 [2] [1 2]) => true
```

But now `conso` can be used as a generator if one argument is a variable:

```
 (run 1 [x]
    (conso 1 [2] x)) => ([1 2])

 (run 1 [x]
    (conso 1 x [1 2])) => ([2])
```

In logic programming the unification answers the question: *What the world should look like for this relation to be satisfied*?

A `non-relational` operator or function is operator that doesn't work as a relation but as a simple function, so unification taking any parameter as variable is not possible.

This happened for instance with operators such as `>` and `<` before `CLP` over finite domains was introduced in namespace `clojure.core.logic.fd`.

*Many of the concepts here you can find in [this talk](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=irjP8BO1B8Y) by Ambrose Bonnaire-Sergeant.*

Comment: Could you give example of why conda and condu are non relational but conde is?

Comment: `conde` explores all the branches, `conda` works as the operator cut in prolog and finishes when the first solution was found. So `conda` doesn't find all the results that satisfy the relation, but only the first.

Comment: So wich of the 4 points you specify in the answere is it that makes conda not a relation?

Comment: conda is not relational because you depend on the order of the rules to determine their logical meaning, so the non determinism principle is not satisfied