# pseudo-relation in core.logic

Tags: clojure, clojure-core.logic

In `core.logic` of function, I see the below definition for `clojure.core.logic/everyg`.

> A pseudo-relation that takes a coll and ensures that the goal g
>   succeeds on every element of the collection.

What exactly a `pseudo-relation` means in this context?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a good explanation of relational (and non-relational): [What does non-relational mean in practice for core.logic?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33787512/what-does-non-relational-mean-in-practice-for-core-logic) Another bit of background is `everyg` was renamed from `everyo` in [this commit](https://github.com/clojure/core.logic/commit/f831accb0659d04fde043288826942dda6650dfa) because the `o` suffix should only used for relations.

One property of relational goals is that they can contribute answers when all/some/none of their inputs are non-ground. `conso` is relational and so we can ask what are the values that satisfy the relation where `l` is `a` prepended to `d`, where all variables are fresh:

```
(run* [a d l] (conso a d l))
=> ([_0 _1 (_0 . _1)])
```

This tells us `a` (`_0`) is fresh, `d` (`_1`) is fresh, and `l` (`(_0 . _1)`) is `a` prepended to `d`. While none of these values are ground, we can still see the *relationship* between them in the answer.

The same is not true for `everyg`:

```
(run* [g coll] (everyg g coll)) ;; Don't know how to create ISeq from: clojure.core.logic.LVar
```

`everyg` can't tell us what the *relationship* between `g` and `coll` is, nor can it tell us what `g` *or* `coll` might be if we supply either ground value:

```
(run* [coll] (everyg succeed coll)) ;; throws
(let [coll (repeatedly 3 lvar)]     ;; throws too
  (run* [g]
    (everyg g coll)))
```

While `everyg` itself isn't a relation, you can pass it a goal `g` and `coll` of fresh and/or ground variables:

```
(let [coll (cons 1 (repeatedly 2 lvar))] ;; 1 prepended to two fresh logic vars
  (run* [q]
    (== q coll)
    (everyg #(fd/in % (fd/domain 0 1)) coll)))
=> ((1 0 0) (1 1 0) (1 0 1) (1 1 1))
```

This example will give the same answers regardless of the position of the `everyg` goal, which is another property of relational goals.

And we can pass the `conso` relation to `everyg` with all fresh logic variables and still see the relationship in the answer, exactly as it was above with the `conso` example:

```
(run* [a d q]
  (everyg #(conso a d %) [q]))
=> ([_0 _1 (_0 . _1)])
```

So with some caveats, `everyg` can be used relationally which is why I think it's considered *pseudo-relational* rather than non-relational.